# Sessions will not work in IE for more than one use

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

I have been working on my website in Chrome and I decided to open it in IE to see how it looked and it was great except for one thing. All of my sessions would work one time and then the next time they were to be called, they didnt work. In Chrome it would carry the session across a few pages as I needed it, but IE only uses the session one time and then stops using it.

Page 1

```
<form action="step2" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="NumberOfCars" value="2" /> 2 Cars <input type="radio" name="NumberOfCars" value="3" /> 3 Cars    <input type="radio" name="NumberOfCars" value="4" /> 4 Cars    <input type="radio" name="NumberOfCars" value="5" checked/> 5 Cars
</form>
```

Next Page (it works on this page)

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php $_SESSION['NumberOfCars']=$_POST['NumberOfCars'];?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['NumberOfCars'];?>
```

Third Page (does NOT work here)

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['NumberOfCars'];?>
```

I have a lot more variables that I am doing on each page, this is jsut an example of of one. all of them have the same problem. Thanks for any help you can give to this problem.

Comment: You probably may need to use `[]` (array) in your `name="NumberOfCars"` such as `name="NumberOfCars[]"` give that a try and see, however I'm not 100% sure about that, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I tried that, but it didnt work

Comment: @Fred-ii- -- that would not do anything good! Instead of getting a string value in `$_POST['NumberOfCars']`, he'd get an array with one value. You would use `[]` in an element name for something like, say, a checkbox. Not for a radio.

Comment: @MitchellWhite I think you should check out the cookie settings in IE, and check the security "zone" that the site is working in, as well as the default zone. This sounds like an IE/settings issue -- the code you posted works, as you have observed in other user agents. What version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: @Chris Ah ok, I stand corrected then.

Comment: IE version=10.0.09200.16660   but if it blocking my cookies, then wont it do it to some of my users. how do i stop that from happening. and other websites that i go to dont have this problem

Comment: its not the cookies being blocked. I just lowered the setting on IE to not block anything, and it still wouldnt work

Comment: Are you doing any `ini_set`s anywhere? Particularly anything involving sessions?

Comment: i have not been using them. someone mentioned it and I put <?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',9999); 
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',9999);
?> in right before session_start(); but that didnt do it for me